# Is it possible to use an excel add-in to save a workbook as an xlsx file?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm able to save worksheet data using the getUsedRange method but this defaults to being a CSV whilst removing the all cell styling and formulas when I save to my API. I want to be able save the entire workbook and post this file to my API without saving to local storage before hand.

Comment: Please include the part that isn't working that you tried

Comment: I think if you open the workbook from a cloud location, then the [Workbook.save](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbook#excel-excel-workbook-save-member(1)) method will save it to that same place.